# Modifying element of const std::vector<T> via const_cast

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, stdvector, const-cast

Does the following program have undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    const std::vector<int> x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    auto f = new Foo{v};
    const_cast<int&>(f->x[1]) = 42; // Legal?
    std::cout << f->x[1] << "\n";
}
```

Note that it *not* using `const_cast` to strip constness from `f->x`, but instead stripping constness from `f->x[x]`, which presumably is represented by a separate array.  Or is a translation allowed to presume that `f->x[1]` is immutable after it is created?

Comment: The struct makes no difference, the issue would be the same as `int main() { const std::vector<int> y(1);  (int&)y[0] = 42; }`

Comment: If you wrote your own class that was an exact clone of std::vector I'm pretty confident that the code would be legal  . Sometimes the standard has extra clauses saying that standard library containers have special properties (e.g. std::vector of incomplete type causes UB); however I can't find anything relevant in this case.

Comment: If you have a library handing out `const std::vector<int> &`s, then be careful that the library isn't assuming the `int`s don't change, even if the compiler can't assume that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is no Undefined Behavior in your example.

The above code does not invoke undefined behavior because the underlying data (int) is mutable. Let's look at a simpler example.

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntPtr {
    int* data;
};

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    const IntPtr p { &a }; 
    *p.data = 10;
    std::cout << a; // Prints 10
}
```

All of this is perfectly legal to do because making `IntPtr` const results in `data` being a constant pointer to an int, NOT a pointer to a constant int. We can modify the data that `p.data` points to; we just can't modify `p.data` itself.

```
const IntPtr p { &a };

*p.data = 10; // This is legal

int b;
p.data = &b; // This is illegal (can't modify const member)
```

**So how does this example apply to `std::vector`?**
Let's add the ability to index into an `IntPtr`:

```
class IntPtr {
    int* data;
   public:
    IntPtr() = default;
    IntPtr(int size) : data(new int[size]) {}
    
    // Even though this is a const function we can return a mutable reference 
    // because the stuff data points to is still mutable. 
    int& operator[](int index) const {
        return data[index]; 
    }
};

int main() {
    const IntPtr i(100); 
    i[1] = 10; // This is fine
};
```

Even though the `IntPtr` is const, **the underlying data is mutable** because it's created by allocating an array of mutable ints. It's the same for `std::vector`: the underlying data is still mutable, so it's safe to `const_cast` it.